# How do I get a custom element definition without instantiating it?

Tags: unit-testing, reference, web-component, stub, custom-element

After looking at the [custom element spec](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/), it's not immediately obvious how I get a reference to a custom element definition without first instantiating it (which can be problematic). Is there a way to directly reference a custom element's prototype?

More concretely, if I have:

```
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
proto.createdCallback = function() { // some heavy operation };
document.registerElement('x-foo', {prototype: proto});
```

At some point later, I would love to reference the prototype with something like:

```
// wish
var XFoo = document.getElementDefinition('x-foo');
```

But instead the only way I've come up with is:

```
// reality
var XFoo = document.createElement('x-foo').__proto__;
```

This is especially problematic when trying to write tests against heavy components - as there's no way to stub out the heavy behavior (with something like `XFoo.createdCallback = // stub;` before the original method is actually called.

Comment: Since the prototype is shared by all instances, just keep a reference to the object somewhere.

Comment: @Pointy that would work for sure. It's more difficult when external libraries are registering components on my behalf (Google Polymer for example). So the question still remains: How do I lookup the definition when I don't have control over the `registerElement` code? That's at the heart of what I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

> there's no way to stub out the heavy behavior

Use a function reference rather than an anonymous function:

```
proto.createdCallback = model.foo;
```

define it:

```
var model = {};
model.foo = function(){/*some heavy operation*/};
```

then stub it by redefining it:

```
var XModel = {};
XModel.foo = function(){/*stub*/};
```

and reference it in the test:

```
XFoo.createdCallback = XModel.foo;
```

**References**

- [AOP Aspect of JavaScript](http://www.lazutkin.com/blog/2008/05/17/aop-aspect-javascript-dojo/)
- [AJAX Interception](http://sloanseaman.com/wordpress/2012/06/10/ajax-interception/)
- [Intro to Aspect Oriented Programming](http://know.cujojs.com/tutorials/aop/intro-to-aspect-oriented-programming)

Answer (score 0):

If you have reference to the constructor of the custom element, you can use it to access the prototype.

```
var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo', {prototype: proto});
XFoo.prototype // this will give u access to the prototype object.
```